# How do I scroll a scrollable div to the exact center?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I go about programmatically scrolling a div to center it's contents?

This is what I'm trying and it's not working

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zBv3v/1/)

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var outerDiv = $("#outerDiv");
    var img = $("img");
    outerDiv[0].scrollTop = img.height() / 2;
    outerDiv[0].scrollLeft = img.width() / 2;
});
```

The content of the div can change dynamically, it will be resizeable.
The fiddle is just to get a working concept of the problem so I can apply to the solution to the actual production code.

**Edit**: To clarify, I want the contents of the div to be centered when I click the button.  Not to set the scroll top/left to 50% as I've already got.

**Edit 2**: I've updated the jquery and the fiddle to setting the scroll to half the contents.

The issue I'm running into is that I need to adjust the scroll points to offset half the width of the actually scrollbar handles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
outerDiv[0].scrollTop = img.height() / 2;
outerDiv[0].scrollLeft = img.width() / 2;
```

This is not correct. Scroll top and left should also depend on `outerDiv`'s height and width.

This works:

```
outerDiv[0].scrollTop = img.height() / 2 - outerDiv.height()/2;
outerDiv[0].scrollLeft = img.width() / 2 - outerDiv.width()/2;
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/zBv3v/3/

Answer (score 1):

Take in account the Div size

Is this what are you looking for ? http://jsfiddle.net/zBv3v/4/

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var outerDiv = $("#outerDiv");
    var img = $("img");
    outerDiv.scrollTop((img.height() - outerDiv.height())/2);
    outerDiv.scrollLeft((img.width() - outerDiv.width())/2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger a function on that click like this (using jQuery):

```
$('#yourButton').click(function() {
    var div = $('#yourDiv');
    div.scrollTo(parseInt(div.height()/2));
    div.scrollLeft(parseInt(div.width()/2));
});
```